# Automating Build of FFMPEG on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVidia acceleration support

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, bash-scripting, compile

I'm trying to automate deployments of a server with a nvidia gpu for video transcoding and need to build ffmpeg from source with nvcc support.

I've gotten the bash script working up to the point where I'm trying to build ffmpeg. I run the script as root user but need to make sure that all users can use ffmpeg.

Here's this part of the script...

```
printf "Installing FFMPEG with Nvidia Support\n"
  cd /root/tmp/build
  git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git nv-codec-headers
  cd nv-codec-headers && make install


mkdir /root/tmp/build/ffmpeg_sources
cd /root/tmp/build/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" \
    ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/build/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/build/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/build/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="/usr/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-cuda-nvcc \
  --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include \
  --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-libaom \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

Everything works until it's running the config and the process just dies with

```
make: *** [ffbuild/common.mak:78: libavfilter/vf_premultiply.o] Terminated
```

It appears to be different ones every time, but if I run it manually it seems to work.

What's causing this?

Comment: Hello there, do you explicitly require a build with NVIDIA CUDA's nvcc support, ie with libnpp enabled? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. I would like to speed up encoding of our live streams.

Comment: I'll look into that and report back. I use BitBN's ffmpeg builder which doesn't use the proprietary CUDA SDK: https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds